# Top Container Background Problem

Tags: html, background, background-image, css

Here's a screenshot:

[header http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/118004/Screen%20shot%202010-04-13%20at%202.50.49%20PM.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/118004/Screen%20shot%202010-04-13%20at%202.50.49%20PM.png)

The red bar on the left is the background I set for the #personal div and I would like it to align to the top of the container, vertically.

The problem is that I have a background for the #container-top div on top of the #container div with absolute positioning. Is there any way to move the #personal div up so there would be no space left?

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="container-top"></div>
    <div id="personal">
      <h1>Jonathan Doe</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliqua erat volutpat.</p>
    </div> <!-- end #personal -->
</div> <!-- end #container -->
```

CSS

```
#container {
  background: url(images/bg-mid.png) repeat-y top center;
  width: 835px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative;
}

#container-top {
  background: url(images/bg-top.png) no-repeat top center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 12px;
  width: 835px;
  top: -12px;
} 

#container-bottom {
  background: url(images/bg-bottom.png) no-repeat top center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 27px;
  width: 835px;
  bottom: -27px;
}

#personal {
  background: url(images/personal-info.png) no-repeat 0px left;
}
```

Comment: I fixed it by adding the upper part of the red bar to 'bg-top.png' and then setting the #personal background position to '-12px left'.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Change the following CSS:

```
    #personal {
  background: url(images/personal-info.png) no-repeat 0px left;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
```

You need to `position` this element `relative` to it's parent; `container`, so that it fits where you want. The `top` and `left` properties are how far away from the *top left corner* of the parent `div` you want the particular element.

**Or this:**

```
#personal {
      background: url(images/personal-info.png) no-repeat 0px left;
    margin-top:-10px; /*px value that works*/
    }
```

This will take its current position within it's parent div and render it 10 pixels higher than it is currently positioned.

Comment: This doesn't change anything at all, does it?

Comment: As far as I see, it should shove it up where he wants it, or have I gotten something wrong?

Comment: The container-top background disappears.

Comment: Try changing it to `position:absolute;`

Comment: I have other content below the personal div.

Comment: Or perhaps a `margin-top:-10px;/*px value that works*/` might be the way to go?

Comment: `#container-top` is not `#personal`'s parent, btw.

Comment: No, it's not. I am reading his code all skew-iff. rethink and rephrase. I think a negative margin might work.

Answer (score 1):

**[Edit: revamped.]**

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="container-inner">
    <div id="personal">
      <h1>Jonathan Doe</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliqua erat volutpat.</p>
    </div> <!-- end #personal -->
  </div> <!-- end #container-bg -->
</div> <!-- end #container -->
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  background: url(images/bg-mid.png) repeat-y top center;
  width: 835px;
  /*margin: 40px auto;*/
  margin: 28px auto 40px auto;
  position: relative;
}

#container-inner {
  background: url(images/bg-top.png) no-repeat top center;
}

#personal {
  background: url(images/personal-info.png) no-repeat 0px left;
  padding-top: 12px;
}
```

Is this according to what you wish to do?

Comment: That would be a better way to do it.

Comment: The backgrounds are transparent, so setting them on top of each other would create a double shadow.

Comment: But you asked to move the 3rd background up. How will it not create a double-shadow as well, the way you ask it? Please clarify.

Comment: I totally misunderstood the question. Let me think and rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

Unless if I'm missing something, I see what you posted producing the results you want.

I'm wondering if you've applied a reset CSS to your styles? If not you could look at the [yahoo user interface css reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/) or [Eric Meyer's reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html).

The browser might have some default padding and margin spacing.

You include the reset CSS before your other styles. Perhaps you already know this, but it's worth asking.

Comment: I have a reset file. I don't want the gap above the red background.